# Mass killing stale backgrounded jobs

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, osx, job-control

```
$ jobs
[1]   Stopped                 emacsclient -nw components/frontend/app/views/frontend/dashboard/index.html.erb
[2]   Stopped                 emacsclient -nw components/frontend/app/views/frontend/dashboard/index.html.erb
[3]   Stopped                 emacsclient -nw ./components/frontend/app/views/frontend/dashboard/_source.html.erb
[4]   Stopped                 emacsclient -nw components/frontend/app/views/frontend/dashboard/source/_articles.html.erb
[5]   Stopped                 emacsclient -nw components/frontend/app/controllers/frontend_controller.rb
[6]   Stopped                 emacsclient -nw components/frontend/app/views/frontend/managed_sources/completion.html.erb
[7]   Stopped                 emacsclient -nw components/frontend/app/views/frontend/users/show/_tabbed_navigation.html.erb
[8]   Stopped                 emacsclient -nw components/frontend/app/views/frontend/managed_contacts/index.html.erb
[9]   Stopped                 emacsclient -nw components/frontend/app/views/frontend/users/_form.html.erb
[10]   Stopped                 emacsclient -nw components/frontend/test/features/opportunities/delete_test.rb
[11]   Stopped                 emacsclient -nw components/frontend/app/controllers/frontend/managed_sources_controller.rb
[12]   Stopped                 emacsclient -nw components/frontend/test/features/managed_sources/new_and_create_test.rb
[13]-  Stopped                 emacsclient -nw components/frontend/app/views/frontend/managed_contacts/index.html.erb
[14]+  Stopped                 emacsclient -nw components/frontend/app/views/frontend/managed_sources/new_source_profile.html.erb
```

It takes me way to long to clear these jobs.
I repeatedly do
    fg
    C-x C-c (which means "exit emacs")

right now. Is there an easier way?

update: I don't want to kill the emacs server. I'm simply trying to quickly close backgrounded emacsclient processes.

Comment: See [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html). There is following advice: _As an exception, when Emacs is started as a daemon, all frames are considered client frames, and C-x C-c never kills Emacs. To kill a daemon session, type M-x kill-emacs._ But M-x kill-emacs won't save changed files.

Comment: I updated the question, clarifying my intentions.

Comment: According to doc (same website as above) you should start emacsclient with -n option. _If you type C-x C-c (save-buffers-kill-terminal) in a client frame, that command does not kill the Emacs session as it normally does (see Exiting). Instead, Emacs deletes the client frame; furthermore, if the client frame has an emacsclient waiting to regain control (i.e., if you did not supply the ‘-n’ option)_

Comment: Instead of `-nw`, have you considered visiting the files in your existing server frame. The command `emacsclient -e '(find-file "/path/to/file")'` has the advantage of returning immediately so there are no jobs to delete.